# Div Dropdown Menu Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I've decided to have a trickier approach to coding a menu. Seems I like to torture myself.

Anyhow, I created a div menu:

```
<div class="menu-bar">
    <div class="menu-item"><span class="menu-text">HOME</span></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><span class="menu-text">ABOUT US</span>
        <div class="sub-menu-items">
            <div class="sub-menu-item">History</div>
            <div class="sub-menu-item">Mission, vision and values</div>
            <div class="sub-menu-item">B-BBEE</div>
            <div class="sub-menu-item">Team</div>
            <div class="sub-menu-item">Professional Affiliations</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item"><span class="menu-text">SECTORS</span></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><span class="menu-text">SERVICES</span></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><span class="menu-text">CSR</span></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><span class="menu-text">PROJECTS</span></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><span class="menu-text">SUSTAINABILITY</span></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><span class="menu-text">CONTACT US</span></div>
</div>
```

My issue comes in with the sub menu `.sub-menu-items`. I have no idea how to make it stay open once the mouse moves out of the About us block and into the sub menu.

Here is the current Javascript code I have:

```
$('.sub-menu-items').hide();
$('.menu-text').hover(function(e) {
// Show highlight
    $(this).toggleClass('menu-text-hover');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('menu-item-hover');
    if($(this).html().indexOf('ABOUT',0) !== -1)
        $('.sub-menu-items').show('fast');
},function(e) {
// Hide highlight
    $(this).toggleClass('menu-text-hover');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('menu-item-hover');
    if($(this).html().indexOf('ABOUT',0) !== -1)
        $('.sub-menu-items').hide('fast');
});
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.menu-bar           { position:absolute; top:159px; height:54px; width:1024px; background-color:#fafafa; z-index:2; }
.menu-item          { display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; position:relative; left:79px; height:54px; text-align:center; width:105px; border-right:dotted thin #000; border-bottom:dotted thin #000; background-color:#fafafa; }
.menu-item-hover    { border-bottom:none; }
.menu-text          { display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; height:52px; width:101px; position:relative; left:2px; top:1px; text-align:center; border-top-right-radius:0px; margin-left:2px; margin-top:2px; margin-right:2px; }
.menu-text-hover    { border-top-right-radius:20px; background-color:#445921; color:#fff; cursor:pointer; }

.sub-menu-items     { position:absolute; display:inline-block; top:55px; width:105px; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); font-size:12px; z-index:100; }
.sub-menu-item      { background:url(../images/devider-horizontal.png) no-repeat center top; display:block; height:40px; }
.sub-menu-item:last { background-image:none; display:block; height:40px; }
```

Can anyone assist me in achieving my goal of making the dropdown menu stay visible when the mouse is still over it?

Comment: A menu should be an unordered list, not divs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rebuild your code a bit:

```
$('.sub-menu-items').hide();
$('.menu-item').hover(function(e) {
    var el = $(this).children(".menu-text");
    el.toggleClass('menu-text-hover');
    $(this).toggleClass('menu-item-hover');
    if (el.html().indexOf('ABOUT', 0) !== -1)
        $(this).find('.sub-menu-items').show('fast');
}, function(e) {
    var el = $(this).children(".menu-text");
    el.toggleClass('menu-text-hover');
    $(this).toggleClass('menu-item-hover');
    if (el.html().indexOf('ABOUT', 0) !== -1)
        $(this).find('.sub-menu-items').hide('fast');
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vnRV4/

---

The good issue raised @epascarello in the comments. You should better use nested lists instead of div blocks. Moreover, it will be good to replace `$('.sub-menu-items').hide()` with CSS style `.sub-menu-items { display: none; }` in order to prevent flashing on page load.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I did everything in div's (stupidly) and then when I took it over to lists, nothing worked. So I'm back to divs now. Very pressed for time on this, so I'll work on it some more when I've finished it. You know, refine it! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use setTimeout and a flag check with this.

outside the functions:

```
var submenuhovered=false;
```

on hide function:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    if(submenuhovered==false){
        $(this).siblings(".sub-menu-items").hide();
    }
},200);
```

on submenu mouseover function

```
submenuhovered = true;
```

on submenu mouseout function

```
submenuhovered = false;
```

or you can use the menu element's .data() collection instead of the global variable.

```
$("menu").data("submenuhovered","true");
```